# wordpress add comment like stackoverflow

Tags: ajax, wordpress, comments

i have posted this link ages ago regarding wordpress:

[wordpress - having comments inline ajax like in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196993/wordpress-having-comments-inline-ajax-like-in-stackoverflow)

and i think that i maybe didn't describe my request properly as each of the given solutions dont actually do what i am looking for:

I would like it when i click on "Add Comment" under my post, to have it simply show an inline form ajax style to avoid users having to click first to a seperate comments page

this is what happens when i click on "Add Comment" in stackoverflow and i never have to leave the main index page.

Comment: You were not clear in either your original question or any of the comments you posted on answers. Why did you not just edit and clarify your original question back then instead of just throwing a bounty on it and expecting people to know what you really meant?

Comment: after looking at the original question, i think it could have been more explicit but it does mention the key points.  I am not sure if you can bounty a question twice, so that is why i raised up a second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this plugin would do most if not all of what you need:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajaxd-wordpress/installation/